# Identify 80s(?) YA novel. Technology is from legendary past, seen as cursed, magic is accepted. Female protagonist

Tags: story-identification

The time of technology has passed into legend. The world is now pastoral. There were a series of books revolving around the female character and how she had an affinity with the ancient machines which were somehow seen as cursed (radiation?). I remember one scene in which she discovers yellow diggers in a cave where they had been sealed up.

Vague - but so want to track it down as it was probably the first SF/Fantasy I read.

Additional: I'm pretty certain the author was female.

Comment: Hrm...brings the Shannara series to mind with the passage of technology that still remains in locations.

Comment: Sounds simlar to Empire of the East, but EofE had a male protagonist who had an affinity for technology in a world that had come to be dominated by magic.

Comment: Was this set in England?  If so, I believe they were shelved next to John Christopher's Tripod Trilogy in my school library.  (Not a large collection; but it probably was another 'C' author.

Comment: It wasn't Shannara, it was not and elves and dwarves sort of fantasy.

@Dan Neely I think it may well have be England-based and I moved on to John Christoper shortly afterwards, so there may be a lead there.

Comment: I'm almost certain that the books I'm remembering were post-nuclear war.  I'd've read them sometime between the late 80's and mid 90's, but the bulk of my schools libraries were purchased in the 60's; so the books themselves are most likely from then.

Comment: Possibly the Darkover novels by Marion Zimmer Bradley? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darkover_series

Comment: @Donald.McLean definitely not the books I'm remembering.

Comment: There are a lot of stories with that description.  like the Crystalis video game's story for instance

Comment: @DanNeely I remember that I thought it was post-nuclear war too, though I remember the librarian was surprised wen I mentioned that as she thought it was simply an alternative world.

I've been trying to remember the name for about ten years now!

Comment: @Donald.McLean Not Darkover (though they are good)

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like: Isobelle Carmody's *Obernewtyn Chronicles*.

Ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obernewtyn_Chronicles

Books include:

- Obernewtyn (1987)
- The Farseekers (1990)
- Ashling (1995)
- The Keeping Place (1999)
- The Stone Key (2008)
- The Sending (2011)
- The Red Queen (unscheduled released)

A [review of Obernewtyn](http://www.librarything.com/work/26139) supports the "pastoral" and "cursed / radiated machines" aspects:

> Apparently [...] humanity made machines that destroyed the world, irradiating
>   and polluting it. Many people died immediately, but some hardy farmers
>   survived. These farmers established a new order, one opposed to
>   technology and worshipful of Lud (their God). They also dictated a
>   policy to kill any seditious people and those affected by radiation,
>   Misfits.

The [wiki page for Obernewtyn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obernewtyn_%28novel%29) (the first book) says that the leaders "are secretly searching for the old weapons that had sent the world to the brink of despair" -- this could fit with machines being sealed in caves and people searching for them, such as you note when the protagonist "discovers yellow diggers in a cave where they had been sealed up."

The [wiki page for the entire series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obernewtyn_Chronicles) describes various mental talents of the Misfits, such as **teknoguilding:**

> A deep affinity with machines and a love for study, especially of technology (and therefore of the Beforetime). Possibly entails some ability to manipulate machines mentally.

Granted, it also lists the Misfits who have each talent, and the female protagonist (Elspeth) is not listed in that group -- however, the talent definitely exists as you recall it. (That said, Elspeth *does* have the powers of telepathy / mind-reading / mind-control of both animals and humans.)

Lastly, the author is female, and her last name starts with 'C', so it would have indeed been next to the *Tripod Trilogy*.

Answer (score 1):

He's certainly not a female, but he would be shelved near the 'C's - Peter Dickinson?  Wrote a trilogy, 'The Changes' in the late 60s: The Weathermonger, Heartsease and The Devil's Children. Adapted for TV in the '70s.

Comment: Not what I was talking about here ... but thank you so much, that was another of my old favorites that I was trying to track down!

So the female author is still a mystery, but you answered a question I hadn't yet asked :-)